# Is it guaranteed to get the latest signed document after receiving DocuSign Event Notification 'Completed'?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Our integration with Docusign is set up to receive Docusign event notifications per envelope like this:

```
new EventNotification()
        {
            Url = callbackUrl,
            UseSoapInterface = "false",
            IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
            IncludeTimeZone = "true",
            SignMessageWithX509Cert = "true",
            RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
            EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>,             
            RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>
            {
                new RecipientEvent{ RecipientEventStatusCode = "Completed"},
                new RecipientEvent{ RecipientEventStatusCode = "Declined"}
            }
        };
```

After receiving notification when a signer signs, we download the document from DocuSign using DocuSign C# client like this

```
        var envApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
        var documentContent = await envApi.GetDocumentAsync(account.AccountId, envelopeId, "combined");
```

In many cases intermittently we don't get the final document that contains the signature of the last signer.

Do you have to listen to another event in order to download the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that we (DocuSign) are working on to fix. Currently there is a race condition between the `Envelope Complete` notification being sent and the final completion of the envelope's processing.

Until the problem is solved, your software could wait a minute (or 2 minutes if you want to be conservative) after receiving the notification before it makes the document download request.

I will update this answer as I receive more information from DocuSign Engineering.

Answer (score 2):

There's a different between Envelope being complete and Recipient being Complete.
You are listening to recipients, and not envelopes.
After the last recipient is complete, it still take a short while for the entire envelope to be complete.
If you listen to envelope complete, you may be able to resolve this issue. However, Larry noted that there may be another race condition for that event as well. I still suggest you try that, but doing this:

```
new EventNotification()
        {
            Url = callbackUrl,
            UseSoapInterface = "false",
            IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
            IncludeTimeZone = "true",
            SignMessageWithX509Cert = "true",
            RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
            EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent> { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "completed", IncludeDocuments = "true" }),              
            RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>
            {
                new RecipientEvent{ RecipientEventStatusCode = "Completed"},
                new RecipientEvent{ RecipientEventStatusCode = "Declined"}
            }
        };
```

Comment: Excellent spotting of the use of Recipient.complete vs Envelope.complete

Comment: IMHO even though there is a difference between envelope complete and signer complete events, both those events should not be fired if the document is not ready.

Comment: You are correct @LightTechnician